# Regex - Match Entire String Unless

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression that will match everything in the string unless it has a certain word in it.  Taking this string for example:

```
http://12.34.567.890/sqlbuddy
```

The expression that matches everything is:

```
^.*$
```

...Which needs to be modified so that it will **not** match the string at all if it contains the word "sqlbuddy".  I thought that a negative lookahead would do it, but that's not working for me.

For example, I tried this, which doesn't work:

```
^(?!sqlbuddy).*$
```

How should I modify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example doesn't work because it assumes `sqlbuddy` is in the beginning of the string. You need to change it to the following, so that `sqlbuddy` can appear anywhere in the string:

```
^(?!.*sqlbuddy.*).*$
```

However, if you really just want to check if your string contains a given word, then maybe a `"http://12.34.567.890/sqlbuddy".contains("sqlbuddy")` will suffice.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm using it with mod_rewrite so I can't use .contains(), but it works and so does the other answer below.  However, for some reason it doesn't match using the regex tester at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Allen, check out rubular, it's what I use for my Regex testing, and I really like it.

Comment: +1 but minor tweak: you don't need the `.*` after `sqlbuddy`. This is enough: `(?m)^(?!.*?sqlbuddy).*$` or `(?m)^(?!.*sqlbuddy).*$` depending on whether you want to go lazy or backtrack.

Answer (score 4):

Also, this worked for me: Position of the string 'sqlbuddy' doesn't matter.

`^((?!sqlbuddy).)*$`

Answer (score 0):

...also (for other people), if you want to search only in a specific place of a [long] string (long text with multiple matches), you can use:

```
first_part_of_string(?!.*sqlbuddy.*)second_part_of_string
```

or, more permissive:

```
first_part_of_string.*(?!.*sqlbuddy.*).*second_part_of_string
```

Comment: fyi, the second .* after the ')' in the permissive part won't do a thing as you include those characters in the capture or just before it if the negative lookahead is falsy. also you don't need them at all in the lookahead or the former example, just one will suffice. but the '.' will break on newline, I norlammy do [\S\s]* instead