# regex to match entire string unless string is /

Tags: ruby, regex

What is a good regex to match the entire string, unless the string is "/"?

Use case:This is for a rewrite rule. Working with rack-rewrite, which is appending a trailing /.

I need:

```
/foo -> /newpath/foo
/ -> newpath
```

The second example does not have a trailing slash.

Took a look at [Regex - Match Entire String Unless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918889/regex-match-entire-string-unless) but didn't know how to make it work for all except "/".

Working in Ruby.

Comment: Why a regex when you could say `"string" != "/"`?

Comment: @squiguy cause rewrite rule you write in .htaccess using regex

Comment: @alfasin In that case a negated character class should do.

Comment: What the heck does `The second example does not have a trailing slash.` mean?  None of the paths you posted has a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely wrong to use a regex for this purpose, but per your request:

```
re = %r{(?!\A/\z)(\A.*\z)}

"foo"[re] #=> "foo"
" /"[re]  #=> " /"
"/ "[re]  #=> "/ "
"/"[re]   #=> nil
```

If you want to get the string unless a string is `"/"`, the way to do it is:

```
string unless string == "/"
```

Comment: I added its use to the answer.

Comment: If it is entirely wrong to use a regex for this purpose, how would you do it?

Comment: The regex works. It just needs to escape the forward slash: `(?!\A\/\z)(\A.*\z)`

Comment: Yes, but this is part of a rewrite rule. I don't know how to add ruby to the match part...but maybe it could be done with 2 rules. I agree with you. This is a very cryptic solution.

Comment: You're right. It is easier and clearer to do it with 2 rules:   `rewrite %r{/foo(.*)}, '/newpath/foo$1'
  rewrite %r{/(.*)}, '/newpath$1'`

Comment: Your two rule solution doesn't produce the mapping you said you wanted in your op.

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite %r{.*}, lambda { |match, rack_env|
    url = match[0]
    url == "/" ? "newpath" : "/newpath#{url}"
  }
```

Comment: your solution is a bit interesting to me... But would like to know why did you use `lambda` ?

Comment: @Priti, The op already did in one of the comments.  Here it is again: https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite